# Integration with Facebook Discussions

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm a newbie with Facebook programming and I'm trying to integrate my **Desktop application written in Windows with Facebook discussions**.  My desktop application should be able to read all messages posted on the Facebook discussions board and write into a file on the local system.
Is there any way for retrieving/accessing the groups messages (in the discussion board) for a specific group (guid) using the API or FQL queries?  Pls. advice.  Any explanation with programming code snippets will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any expert opinion yet?  Appreciate quick response on this.

Answer (score 1):

As facebook will close discussion in a few days, it may be not relevant info for you, but...

No, facebook doesn't provide ani API to get topics/comments from discussion board. We have done our http://apps.facebook.com/discussions_parser/ by simply parsing pages with selenium(htmlUnit couldn't get a non bookmarkable ajax loaded pages).